Linux shell coding for adding a column with % (percentage)
I need help with Linux shell code for adding a column with % percentage calculation.
file1:
Name    Count
Tom 10
Tom 7
Tom 5
Tom 4

Result in file2 as shown
file2:
Name    Count   Percent
Tom 10  38.5
Tom 7   26.9
Tom 5   19.2
Tom 4   15.4


I'm not sure if I understand the question well.
To calculate the total count, we need to calculate the total count of all the "Count" values.
Calculate the percentage for each line using the total count, we can then
calculate the percentage for each row and add it as a new column.
Assuming file1.txt contains:
Name Count
Tom 10
Tom 7
Tom 5
Tom 4

This should generate desired output:
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1: Calculate the total count
total=$(awk 'NR>1 {sum+=$2} END {print sum}' file1.txt)

# Step 2: Add percentage column and save to file2.txt
awk -v total="$total" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Name", "Count", "Percent"}
NR>1 {percent=($2/total)*100; printf "%s\t%d\t%.1f\n", $1, $2, percent}' file1.txt > file2.txt

After running the script, file2.txt will contain:
Name    Count   Percent
Tom     10      38.5
Tom     7       26.9
Tom     5       19.2
Tom     4       15.4


Thank you so much Max! it works; I have a new set of data and I tried to make it works with your codes.  I will reach out if I need additional help!  Thanks!

Wow, I'm impressed that went right from the start! Can you please mark the solution as Accepted? That helps keep these threads short. Good luck!

Solution Accepted!

@bobo Sigh… This is how accepting works.

Thank you, @bobo and everyone! It's really gratifying to know that I could be helpful. It's a rewarding feeling, especially when the acceptance button is pressed—it helps keep the threads short and concise.
